# How can I check which SMC version I am using?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, macos

I formatted my hard driver and reinstalled ML. I'd like to know whether I need to reinstall [the latest SMC update](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1559) or that once I install it is saved forever on the system.

I think that I don't need to reinstall it, because power sleep is enabled, and if I'm not mistaken it updates this feature, am I wrong?

In other words: Can I check which SMC I'm using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes.** To check which **SMC** you're using just:

1. From the Apple () menu, choose **About This Mac**.
2. Click **More Info**.
3. Click **System Report**.
4. Open the Hardware section to reveal Model Identifier, Boot ROM version, and SMC version numbers.

Just so that you know, if you are unsure whether your computer needs a particular update, simply download and open the update installer. The installer will alert you if the firmware update is already installed or not needed.

Comment: Thanks for the info! what is the latest SMC update of the rMBP?

Comment: The one you link to in your question. :)

Comment: I meant which value should it have in system report :)

Comment: OK, found the number, it's 2.3f32 (SMC 1.0)(http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1237)

Comment: Doh! I couldn't find the rMBP in that list!